# How is it possible to pass the data from tableview controller to next viewController with didSelectRowAtIndexPath(i.e. Without using Segue)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
SecondViewController *second=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"    bundle:nil];
second.getString=[getArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Action" sender:nil];  }
```

How to pass data from one view to another,In my app there are some objects i want that when i tap on any cell then that value should be shown on next ViewController which having `UILabel`?

Comment: If you want to navigate to next `viewController` then you have to perform segue otherwise you can replace segue with `[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];` to navigate and pass data.

Comment: Questions about passing data from one controller to another really should be banned from SO. They've been asked, and answered thousands of times already.

Comment: Is Segue identifier will also declare?

Answer (score 1):

Create a init method in your SecondViewController  as  shown below.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withData:(NSString *) data {
    if (self = [self initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        self.data = data;
       // write your own code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

In your tableview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` row method get the string and then push the controller as shown below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
NSSting *stringData = @"hi";// get your data and passing to stringData
 SecondViewController *secondVC=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"    bundle:nil withData:stringData];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController: secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

create an instance variable `NSString * sendingText ;// if you want to send text(string)`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    sendingText = [getArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Action" sender:nil];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Action"]) // this check is optional if there is only on segue
    {       
       SecondViewController *second= (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
       second.getString = sendingText;
    }
}
```

in `SecondViewController.h`

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
   UILabel * exampleLabel;
}
@property NSString * getString;
@end
```

and in `SecondViewController.m`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    exampleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:exampleLabel];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    exampleLabel.text = getString;
}
```

Comment: By this code we navigate nested view  and onconsole it shows>>>                    nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

Comment: ACCIDENTLY TRIGGERING THE SAME SEGUE TWICE Once in code, and once from interface builder, but both at the same time...so remove the segue directly from cell and connect it from view controller